# Show table by clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
          $("table").toggle();
        });
      });
  </script>

<!--Technical Specifications Button Code-->

  <div class="w3-center">
    <button class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px; margin-bottom:64px">TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS</button>
  </div>

<!--Technical Specifications Table Design-->

    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    th {
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

<!--Technical Specifications Table-->

    <table class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
```

I have no idea if I should use a "display:none" in my style or if I should make a function that allows the code to be hidden and unhidden. I want this to be as easy as possible, with minimal modifications to my code.

Comment: add an Id to your table, then modify Jquery selector

Comment: Also, your codes are not complete

Comment: I know. I didn't post the entire code because I didn't think people would need all the information in the table. Also, could you write up what the ID in the table would look like and what the modified Jquery selector would look like as well?

Comment: Just add a `table { display: none; }` to your `<style>` element

Comment: @JonathanLam JOHN! YOU'RE THE MAN! Now I have a new problem though. My table is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: @MichaelBertolino I'm glad I helped! But explain "formatted incorrectly"

Comment: https://imgur.com/GYiVcfm and https://imgur.com/d8d8wn9 P.S. Read picture titles for more info

Comment: @JonathanLam I fixed it. It was the border radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for button

```
<button id="myButton" class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px; margin-bottom:64px">TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS</button>
```

Add this to your css

```
table { display: none; }
```

And use these

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
      $("#myTable").toggle();
    });
  });
```

Comment: This solution works too (after changing '#myTable' to 'table'), but, as I told @JonathanLam, my table is now formatted weird

Comment: what you mean `formatted weird`? can you insert an image?@MichaelBertolino

Comment: https://imgur.com/GYiVcfm and https://imgur.com/d8d8wn9 P.S. Read picture titles for more info

Comment: I fixed it. It was the border radius

Comment: Thanks for the help. I spent so long on this and it was three words  haha

Answer (score 2):

`display: none` will do fine to hide your table at the start. See example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("table").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}

#t1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-center">
  <button class="w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px; margin-bottom:64px">TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS</button>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover" style="width:100%" id="t1">
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```